# How to Upload Multiple Files to node js server using Volley?

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, android-volley, retrofit

I am new in android , I want to upload multiple files to my Node.js server , I am using volley for generating request.

I need to store multiple images in array and than need to pass that array to server .

I can upload a single file to server but I am not able to upload multiple files ,  Can anyone help me how can I achieve this .

Thanks

I follow [Retrofit 2 — How to Upload Multiple Files to Server](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-server.)

but I want it through volley.

My Code is

```
private void showChooser() {



    ArrayList<Integer> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
    moviesList.add(R.drawable.cart);
    moviesList.add(R.drawable.carts);
    moviesList.add(R.drawable.userimage);
    moviesList.add(R.drawable.voucher);
    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < moviesList.size(); i++) {

        File file = new File(String.valueOf(moviesList.get(i)));

        if(file.exists()){
            final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse(String.valueOf(moviesList.get(i)));
            builder.addFormDataPart("my_images[]",file.getName(),RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE,file));
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Hello", "file not exist ");
        }


    }



    RequestBody requestBody = builder.build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urls)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);


    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            Log.d("Response is :",String.valueOf(response));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    });
```

Comment: Can you please show what you tried already?

Comment: @KlausGütter check , I upload what i am doing . But not achieve it yet